# styling using attribute selector on Angular's ng attributes

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, angularjs

Is it bad practice to style an element based on Angular's ng attributes? Why or why not? Please explain your answer.

**Example:**

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul ng-controller="todoCtrl">
    <li></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

```
/* CSS */
[ng-controller="todoCtrl"] {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You want to be careful not to tie your implementation code too closely to your presentation code. Both your styles and your controllers will be much less portable (i.e. reusable) if they are intertwined.